# Adding a 10px padding or margin to a div makes no difference

Tags: html, css

In the following scenario, I'm trying to add a 10px margin or padding to the div that is inside, which has class "url", but nothing works for it.

I can see that giving it a margin of 120px does the job.

How do I do something like what I'm attempting to do, and still have a 10px margin or padding to the div with class url?

Also, the div with class status will not appear aligned horizontally.

I don't mind anything being changed, as long as it'll work. Can you help? I gave up trying.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1kha7xkb/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dev</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .outer {
            font-family: Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace;
            font-size: 12px;
            border:1px solid #e1e1e8;
            background:#f7f7f9;
        }

        .site {
            float:left;
            width:100px;
            padding:10px;
            border-right:1px solid #ECECF0;
            background:#fbfbfc;
            color:#BEBEC5;

        }

        .url {
            padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
            color:#D14;
            text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;

        }

        .status {
            float:right;
            padding:3px;
            background:#F5f5f5;
            border:1px solid #ececF0; 
            color:#D14;
            text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
            font-size:10px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="site">site</div>
    <div class="url">http://www.google.com
        <div class="status">active</div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed your padding to:
{padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;} and I saw a clear change... Do you want the text inside of the div to have a padding?

Comment: @skibbi_bizzle For which div?

Comment: with the class URL? Is that the correct one? If I set them all to 0 their is a clear change...

Comment: But that already has that type of padding...

Comment: I misread the question, Let me check it out again...

Comment: `I can see that giving it a margin of 120px does the job.` can you share the fiddle using this style?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai http://jsfiddle.net/1kha7xkb/4/ here it is.

Comment: @Norman I found that if you float:left and margin-left:10px it works but it messes with the structure...http://jsfiddle.net/1kha7xkb/7/ but it does have the padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin-left` not applied because you have not add `float:left` for the url div. So that it is started it is calculation from left position zero onwards. It works for you `margin-left:120px` because the first div `width + padding` is 120px.

I have made other changes to align your `active box` to right, you can check it in my fiddle.

You have to clear your float div using `clear:both`

**HTML**

```
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="site">site</div>
    <div class="url">Need some 10px space here from the right
        <div class="status">active</div>
    </div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .url {
        float:left;
        padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
        color:#D14;
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
        margin-left:20px;  
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1kha7xkb/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `.url` inner content in a div and add your padding to it. Something like `.inner-url`.

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="site">site</div>
<div class="url"><div class="inner-url">Need some 10px space here from the right</div>
    <div class="status">active</div>
</div>
```

```
.inner-url{
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1kha7xkb/9/

or

Just add margin-right to your `.site` class

http://jsfiddle.net/1kha7xkb/5/